# How can I add condition min only 3 character when search on the autocomplete?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, autocomplete, vue-component, vuetify.js

My template like this :

```
<v-autocomplete
        v-model="model"
        :items="items"
        :loading="isLoading"
        :search-input.sync="search"
        chips
        clearable
        hide-details
        hide-selected
        item-text="name"
        item-value="symbol"
        label="Search for a coin..."
        solo
      >
```

My component like this :

```
watch: {
    search (val) {
      // Items have already been loaded
      if (this.items.length > 0) return

      this.isLoading = true

      // Lazily load input items
      fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/')
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(res => {
          this.items = res.data
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        })
        .finally(() => (this.isLoading = false))
      }
  },
```

My codepen and demo like this :

https://codepen.io/positivethinking639/pen/GRgGJNN?editors=1010

I try add : `if(val.length >= 3) { ... }` ,

but there exist error :

```
[Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "search": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null"
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the error, when adding the length check like so

```js
watch: {
  ...
  search (val) {
    // Items have already been loaded
    if (this.items.length > 0) return

    if (val.length < 3) return;

    this.isLoading = true

    // Lazily load input items
    fetch('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/listings/')
```

If you are checking length somewhere else, the `Cannot read property 'length' of null` error could be fixed by enhancing the expression like this:

```js
if (val && val.length >= 3) { ... }
```